# How to restore /Library/Application Support/Dock/ after deletion

Tags: mojave, dock

I crashed Dock.app by using wal on a heic file that included more than one picture.
Then I wanted to delete the Dock database at /Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db but I accidentally deleted the whole folder.
After a restart, Dock.app doesn’t start. Opening it manually with the command

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
```

Will start the dock for a second - the default Catalina wallpaper is visible, but it will crash right after.
Is there any solution other then reinstalling the entire system?

Comment: You might have success with a combo update but without knowing your macOS version we don't know if such is even available.

Comment: The other solution is to restore from your backup.

Comment: @SteveChambers it’s the newest version of Mojave. I already started a reinstallation. Also, didn’t expect I can break macOS so bad by setting a wallpaper wrong...

Comment: Reinstallation didn't help! I did the simple reinstall, but it didn't seem to help. Do I have to do a full wipe? Where are the wallpapers saved, can anyone help me?

Comment: The behaviour didn't change at all.

Comment: If you have a Time Machine backup, use that. Otherwise I would do a full/clean reinstall, and set up Time Machine next time! It might be possible to find the missing file but if you don't have a backup, I suspect biting the bullet and starting over will ultimately save you time.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I don't have enough space for a full Time Machine backup anywhere ):. I can copy all the files I need. Are you sure there is no way to restore it? Why does a normal reinstall not work? This is by far the dumbest way to break my mac. Btw. Safe Mode or Guest Mode don't help...

Comment: You can extract files from an installer and copy them back using an app called Pacifist.